# How to enable and disable items in alert dialog

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDJV2.jpg)My question is i dont want to select same option twice..
when it is clicked for 1st time it should be disable. later when we choose another item, disabled item should be enabled

public class DialogSelection extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private static DialogSelection dialogSelection;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public static DialogSelection newInstance(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    if (dialogSelection == null) {
        dialogSelection = new DialogSelection();
    }
    dialogSelection.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    return dialogSelection;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String[] items = {"On Duty", "Off Duty", "Sleeper", "Driving"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Selection")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.i("Dialogos", "Option Selected: " + items[item]);

                    switch (items[item]) {
                        case "On Duty":
                            mainActivity.updateTimelineStatus(DriverState.STATE_ONLINE);
                            break;
                        case "Off Duty":
                            mainActivity.updateTimelineStatus(DriverState.STATE_OFFLINE);
                            break;
                        case "Sleeper":
                            mainActivity.updateTimelineStatus(DriverState.STATE_SLEEPER);
                            break;
                        case "Driving":
                            mainActivity.updateTimelineStatus(DriverState.STATE_DRIVING);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

Comment: pls share ur screenshot and how do u want

Comment: hi bro .how to send screenshot

Comment: click edit below ur coding paste ur screenshot

Comment: i Have uploaded just check it

Comment: click itm value get one variable next itm click time value compare equal then  then not do ur operation unequal then do it ur operation

Comment: finish ah bro..

Comment: means i need to compare two value rght??

Comment: yes do compare.

Comment: my intension is when i click one Onduty option. After clicking it should disabled till, i select next option

Comment: are u need that item remove from display of it.

Comment: i dont want to remove,, just it shouldnt be selected,,

Answer (score -1):

are u use string[] replace of list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
    list.add("onduty");
    ...
    add ur need options
    //check is string variable create inside ur class
    if(check!=null)
    {
    list.remove("check")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just written, you can try it.**

```
  private final String[] items = {"On Duty", "Off Duty", "Sleeper", "Driving"};//your data
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;//adapter
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (itemAdapter.getSelectPosition() == i) {
                return;
            }
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            itemAdapter.select(i);
            //your code
            Log.i("Dialogos", "Option Selected: " + items[i]);
            switch (items[i]) {
                case "On Duty":
                    break;
                case "Off Duty":
                    break;
                case "Sleeper":
                    break;
                case "Driving":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (itemAdapter == null) {
            itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items, -1);
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Selection");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setView(listView);//use custom ListView
        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);//user custom Adapter
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        return alertDialog;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Adapter
     */
    private class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private String[] data;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private int selectPosition = -1;//disabled item position

        public void select(int selectPosition) {
            this.selectPosition = selectPosition;
        }

        public int getSelectPosition() {
            return selectPosition;
        }

        public ItemAdapter(Context contexts, String[] data, int selectPosition) {
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
            this.data = data;
            this.selectPosition = selectPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return data[i];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null);//use system default layout
            textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView.setText(data[i]);//set data
            textView.setEnabled(this.selectPosition != i);//disable or enable
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can we display it in grid view

Comment: @shashidhar you only change the  ListView to GridView,and you can set number of columns